# What is the explicit max-min arithmetic use in this transformation?

Tags: systems-of-equations, arithmetic

I am reading the book "Engineering Optimization: Theory and Practice, 5th Edition" on Chapter 7 and page 409 and stumble upon this system of equation

$\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{{\left( {{x_1} + 1} \right)}^2} - 2r\left[ {\max \left( {0,1 - {x_1}} \right)} \right] = 0}\\
{1 - 2r\left[ {\max \left( {0,1 - {x_1}} \right)} \right] = 0}
\end{array}} \right.}&{\left( 1 \right)}\\
{\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\min \left[ {{{\left( {{x_1} + 1} \right)}^2},{{\left( {{x_1} + 1} \right)}^2} - 2r\left( {1 - {x_1}} \right)} \right] = 0}\\
{\min \left[ {1,1 + 2r{x_2}} \right] = 0}
\end{array}} \right.}&{\left( 2 \right)}
\end{array}$

Also $r>0$

I do not know how can they get from (1) to (2) so I think that there is some max-min arithmetic behind it. Therefore, my question is:

What is the underlying max-min arithmetic that transform (1) to (2) ?

Thank you for your enthusiasm !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the two basic properties you need :
$$
\max(x,y) + a = \max(x+a,y+a)
$$
and
$$
c \cdot \max(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
   \max(cx,cy) & \mathrm{if\;} c \ge 0 \\
   \min(cx,cy) & \mathrm{if\;} c \le 0
\end{cases}
$$
In the present case, you have $a = (x_1 + 1)^2$ and $c = -2r$ with $r > 0$.

Comment: But what about the multiplicative and additive identity for the min operation ?

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh  They are the same, except that max/min are reversed in the multiplicative case.

Comment: I am sorry but can you abit more specific because I am not mathematician. I am not well verse with abstractions.

Comment: @TuongNguyenMinh
$$
\min(x,y) + a = \min(x+a,y+a)
$$
and
$$
c \cdot \min(x,y) = 
\begin{cases}
   \min(cx,cy) & \mathrm{if\;} c \ge 0 \\
   \max(cx,cy) & \mathrm{if\;} c \le 0
\end{cases}
$$